# Is it possible to connect a MacBook to two monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

My friend has a MacBook from around when OS X Leopard came out. It's one of the white plastic ones. Can he connect this to two monitors? If not, what does he need to do so?

*Moderator Edit:*

> **Similar, but not exact duplicate:**
>   [Connecting two external monitors to a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, such is possible.  There exist USB to VGA adapters that will allow two or more monitors on a MacBook.  Here's a link to a blog post that reviews one such product:

[REVIEW: EVGA USB VGA Adapter Adds Two or MORE Monitors to MacBook Pro](http://onemansblog.com/2009/04/24/review-evga-usb-vga-adapter-adds-two-or-more-monitors-to-macbook-pro/)

And here's another such product:  [TRITTON Technologies TRI-UV200 SEE2 Xtreme](http://www.trittontechnologies.com/products/TRIUV200.htm)

I use a Tritton USB to VGA adapter with my PC at work, and I am generally satisfied. It works fine for most applications, but don't expect good refresh rates for video playback or video games.  YMMV.

UPDATE: There's also a product from Matrox called DualHead2Go which will expand your VGA port to support two monitors.  It shows Macbook support.  Read up at [Matrox finally adds Mac compatibility to DualHead2Go and TripleHead2Go](http://www.tuaw.com/2006/11/30/matrox-finally-adds-mac-compatibility-to-dualhead2go-and-tripleh/).  I expect this may perform better than the USB adapters.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to cwrea's answer:

The tritton solution seems to be the only one that can do DVI. I'd look into that one.

If this were a MacBook Pro with an Express Card slot, there are Express Card solutions with DVI output out there. But I cannot recommend any particular product.

Honestly, the two displays on a MacBook situation is a bit dire.

Answer (score 1):

Get an external video adapter - if you don't need a lot of rendering performance, a USB-to-DVI video adapter should work fine.  You can use these to add a bunch of outputs (again, as long as raw performance isn't an issue).

I wouldn't be shocked to see a native Thunderbolt solution by year end, though.  (I'm not sure if these comply to the latest DisplayPort spec, but if they do they support daisy-chaining natively using DP rather than DVI...at least once monitors start shipping that support it.)

Comment: agreed - thunderbolt is designed to handle the kind of bandwidth you'd need to render both screens. You'll have to wait like the rest of us.