# Dual monitors (30inch -> 2560 * 1600) on a MacBook Pro

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I would like to connect my MacBook Pro 17 on two monitors
DELL 3008WFP - 30 inch and being able to enjoy a 2560 * 1600 resolution on both monitor.

I've got a TripleHead2Go, unfortunatly it does not support 2560 * 1600

So I'm looking for a hardware connector which would support such a resolution on two 30 inch monitor using my MacBook Pro 17

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that will allow you to do that.  The output on the MacBookPro only supports a [maximum resolution of 2560x1600](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html) (for the current model).  There are USB display adapters, but those only aren't going to support 2560x1600 in any case.

You'd need a laptop that supported dual external displays, but then it wouldn't be a Mac.

**Edit**

Doing some searches, there is this: http://www.villagetronic.com/vidock2/index.htm.  It is pretty expensive however.  [See this question](https://superuser.com/questions/19047/can-the-new-macbook-macbook-pro-support-dual-external-monitors).

Comment: I've already got a regular desktop Windows PC connected on those monitor on DVI1 and wanted to connect the MAC on DVI2.

Comment: I did found this product too :
http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=375076
1/5 of what cost the Vidock2, and less bulkier too. Has anyone got any experience with the belkin ?

Comment: That allows you to hook up a single monitor to two computers and switch between them (along with a keyboard and mouse) not one computer to two monitors.  It's a completely different thing than the Vidock.

Comment: Last time I was forced to use a MacBook Pro I installed Ubuntu on it, the NVIDIA Linux driver, and used the laptop display and an external monitor in dual-monitor mode.