# Is there a way to hook up my may 2010 17" macbook pro to two external monitors?

Tags: external-display, displayport, mini-displayport, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the new MacBook / MacBook Pro Support Dual EXTERNAL Monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/19047/can-the-new-macbook-macbook-pro-support-dual-external-monitors)

I think having three screens would be cool =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DisplayPort v1.2 is digital, and supports **daisy-chaining** as well as packet switching. With the new specification, you will be able to daisy-chain *up to **4** 1920x1200 monitors with one DisplayPort output*. Whether your MacBook Pro (or the mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort adaptor) will support the v1.2 spec is a different question.

Comment: I like this idea... I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

Matrox makes an adapter that allows for two external monitors (note: it comes in DisplayPort, digital, and analog flavors).

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/

Comment: wow... that looks like it would work... but the device is more expensive than the 24" monitor i Just bought (150$)... is there nothing cheaper?

The matrox device is $190+

Comment: Well, there might be other adapters out there, but I would imagine they're not gonna be much cheaper anywhere else.  The problem is that you need an adapter; the MacBooks don't have the capabilities (as far as I know) to natively support two external monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, although you won't get *quite* the same image quality: the [Kensington Universal Multi-Display Adapter](http://us.kensington.com/html/17534.html). It's currently going for $66 on Amazon. It allows you to run a 3rd display via USB versus splitting your video output.

There are other companies that have similar products, so you might be able to find a cheaper model by shopping around.

Comment: Here's one of the similar/cheaper products I referred to [at MonoPrice](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?p_id=6040).

Comment: And here's the [Amazon link](http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN/B002F9NSMQ).