# Macbook pro 15" dual external display

Tags: macbook, display, thunderbolt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to connect a MacBook to two monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/14116/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-macbook-to-two-monitors)

How can I connect two external DVI displays to a 2011 15" MacBook Pro?

Comment: Similar to this: http://superuser.com/questions/14116/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-macbook-to-two-monitors