# Macbook Air (mid 2011) dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to connect a MacBook to two monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/14116/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-macbook-to-two-monitors)

My work has just bought me a Macbook Air (2011 model). My understanding is that this won't support dual external monitors. Is that correct? If so, is there some attachment that I can purchase so that I can continue to use my 2 external monitors?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that, as that isn't referring to a Macbook Air.

Comment: IMO, It's still the same question, with the same answers.  See [This Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/14116/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-macbook-to-two-monitors/14119#14119) for example... But that's why it takes 5 to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something like this [USB monitor adapter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&rls=en&q=usb%20monitor%20adapter&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=4892653317943015340&sa=X&ei=MvJLTsXKJuPSiALT29CLAQ&ved=0CDcQ8wIwAA#ps-sellers). Several of my co-workers have two monitors attached to their MBP's. One via the DisplayPort, and one via USB.

I only use one monitor myself, so I'm not sure if this is the same one they use. It just happened to be the first one listed on Google.

Comment: Cheers. I believe they are one step ahead of me and have actually purchased something like this too!