# Can I leverage my desktop's video card when using my laptop?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, virtualization

Really trying to think outside the box here. I have a laptop which I now use as my primary work machine. I'm really missing having multiple monitors though. Is there anyway I can leverage a video card in another pc to extend my desktop and get my multi monitor setup back?

The laptop is an ASUS-R1F PC with vista.

Thanks.

Comment: Related Question: http://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/), which allows you to use another computer as a secondary monitor. This isn't just a seamless remote control like Synergy or Stardock's Multiply, but actually a second (or third, etc) monitor. Sadly, it is not free.

Comment: This is the type of thing I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Too bad this is not free

Answer (score 6):

Okay, let's think outside the box for a moment!

[**USB to DVI External Video Card, High Resolution, 1600 x 1200**](http://sewelldirect.com/USB-to-DVI-External-Video-Card-High-Resolution.asp)

[image]

That should do and the price is reasonable.

Comment: ooo, outside the box indeed!

Comment: Perfect! The youtube video was really reassuring. While its not leveraging my existing hardware this solves my problem elegantly. Just gotta shell out some cash. Thanks!

Comment: you're more than welcome. feel free to accept it as the answer your were looking for :)

Comment: Well its not the answer I was looking for. I want to leverage my existing hardware if possible. Mike Cooper's answer was the best in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/):

[image: Synergy Screenshot]

Install it on all the machines on your network and you can simply move your mouse pointer from one to another. Anything you open will actually be running on "that" machine, so it's basically a network-KVM. Very slick in practice, I use it all the time for controlling my laptop sitting next to my desktop (since I don't want to use the laptop's keyboard/mouse).

It also shares clipboard/etc between them.

Comment: 1 laptop, multiple monitors, what good will Synergy do in such a setup? Synergy a great solution, but certainly not in this scenario :)

Comment: You've rephrased the situation. The question is "1 laptop, video card in another PC, how do I leverage that?", and the solution is to use both machines with something like Synergy. If the OP changed his mind and wants to buy additional hardware instead of leveraging what he has, he should edit the question to reflect that, imo.

Comment: In fact, it just becomes a dupe of the Related question Diago posted.

Comment: I agree. Which is why i didn't accept the additional hardware answer. But molly is correct, the idea here is 1 laptop, 1 video card in another PC, *1 context*. Synergy will give me a separate context for each machine.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is No.

One way of getting multi-monitor support for a laptop is to buy a docking station. The Dell ones allow you to use the laptop's screen and an external monitor. You also get the chance to use a full sized keyboard.

Comment: Eh, docking stations just remap the current laptop's ports. Already using a full keyboard, mouse, and external monitor. The vid card only supports 1 monitor and a max res of 1650x1060. I need more! :P

Comment: In that case the Dell laptop's we use a work (by no means the top end) must be able to support 2 (or more) outputs.

Comment: The Dell's also have a VGA port on the laptop anyway.

A lot of consumer laptops don't have docking stations anyway, unfortunately.

Comment: OH, so you have 2 monitors hooked up to these laptops via the docking station? Or is it the laptop screen and monitor combo?

Comment: I know the Dell docking stations have a VGA and a DVI port which you can use separately, while the laptop it self only has VGA(the D series Latitudes at least. The new E series has Displayport)

Comment: It's the laptop screen + monitor. I haven't been assigned my laptop yet (and I'm not at work!) so I can't double check the video outputs to verify my assertions - sorry.

Comment: I've seen someone using one monitor on the laptop's VGA port, another on the docking station's DVI port and the integrated display of the laptop all at once. That was with a Thinkpad T43. The better docking stations for Thinkpads even allow you to put a dedicated graphics card in there.

Comment: ah, TheDeeno, your Intel GMA950 isn't exactly a powerhouse but it can do better than that, 2048x1536 is the maximum possible resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is software, such as stardock's multiplity (http://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/) that allows you to control two PCs seamlessly, which could solve your problem, at least while you're local to your PC.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. Like a more integrated remote desktop. Not really what I'm looking for though. I'm really trying to extend my laptop. 2 monitors 1 pc. Not 2 pc's 1 monitor. I tend to have a ton of windows open while doing development. Having access to another pc doesn't help much since I need the windows to all be within the same context.

Comment: Do the windows all really need to be in the same context? I've found that browsing/reference material on another machine/monitor and the ability to copy/paste back and forth is generally sufficient, unless All your windows are part of the same app.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your laptop away somewhere on the network and then use RDP to connect to it. Provided that your other computer has two displays, you can set up the Remote Desktop Client to span multiple monitors.

Comment: this would have the disadvantages associated with creating 1 huge desktop correct?

Comment: Never tried, but I think so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised no one had mentioned the Matrox multimonitor solution [DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/). The nice thing about this solution, is that it works using your existing vga or dvi out. No need to sacrifice one of those rare USB ports on your notebook!