# Notebook with two external monitors

Tags: windows-7, external-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting 2 External Monitors to a Laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop)

I was wondering if it was possible to use 3 displays on a notebook - the integrated one plus two external. I have IdeaPad Z570 with two switchable graphics cards and VGA and HDMI output. So far it seems that it is only possible to use two monitors at a time (it's possible to have the integrated disabled and both external enabled, but I can't seem to work it out to use all three).

Is there a way I could use all three at the same time? Windows 7 recognizes them, I can change their positions etc., but one of them is always greyed out :/

Thanks for help

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop
Same question.

Comment: Well, yeah. But the gadgets don't seem optimal. I wanted to know if there is a _native_ way of doing this. So that I could still work with three independent screens, to resize, move windows, etc. .. Does this mean it is not possible at all?

Comment: @MartinMelka: I suggest that you add your comment to your question, that you prefer achieving this in a native way, without using 3rd party gadgets. Otherwise your question may be taken as a duplicate.