# Laptop with two external displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a Dell latitude E5520 (Laptop) with an HDMI and VGA output running Windows8 Enterprise. I also cant use both my external screens at the same time. This is very frustrating.

Is there no software, perhaps third party that will allow me to use CPU power as GPU power to enable me to use the total of three screens (laptop + 2 external)?

Comment: This is a common issue: Refer to this: http://superuser.com/q/656/161601

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you don't have enough GPU power, the problem is that you don't have two independent outputs that "happen" to show the same thing most of the time; what you want can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio said if the hardware doesn't allow 3 differing outputs there is nothing you can do.

However if the requirement is just for 3 screens, there are USB graphics adaptors and USB driven monitors which might be a solution.

Matrox's [GXM](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/) products are a well know solution to this problem.
A [review](http://www.trustedreviews.com/aoc-e2251fwu-22in-usb-monitor_Monitor_review) of AOC's 22" USB powered monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have actually thought about the USB to VGA solution, but was sceptical if it would work. I assume from your answer that it would?