# Connecting 2 External Monitors to a Laptop in 2013?

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, external-display

I know about the 2009 question: [Connecting 2 External Monitors to a Laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop)

It's 2013 now and I want to know if anything has changed.

I want a laptop with two external displays, to make three in total with the laptop screen.

Or even three external displays with the laptop screen disabled.

Is this possible? If so, what should I look for when choosing a laptop?

Comment: Also check out http://www.superuser.com/help/bounty

Comment: No it isnt' a dublicate. He asks if it's still possible in 2013.

Comment: You're still asking the same question. We cannot possibly open a new question for every topic, every year. If you would like to draw attention and get some new answers, consider placing a bounty on it. See: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](http://superuser.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 0):

No nothing has changed. You can still use the Matrox-Adapter or have a look at laptops who have VGA and HDMI-out. Because most highend-laptops support two monitors.

Comment: My laptop has HDMI out and VGA out. I plug a monitor into each. Do I now have three screens?

Comment: Or does my laptop screen go blank on plugging in the second

Comment: Can I assume that just because my laptop has two display outputs that it will be able to support them both and its own screen simultaneously?

Comment: If you want 3 screens, be aware that having the outputs present is no guarantee that it will work. I have a Dell Studio 1749 laptop; Radeon HD5650 with VGA, HDMI, DisplayPort outputs in addition to the LCD panel. I tried all combinations but could not get more than 2 screens to work simultaneously (Windows 7 64 bit, latest ATI drivers).