# Use two external monitor with a laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors

I will buy a new lapop (Asus 550LB-XO034D) which has a VGA and one HDMI output. Could I use my laptop with two external monitors? I want them to extend the desktop (so I dont want an duplicated, same output on both monitor)

So my question is: laptops VGA and HDMI outputs send the same signal, or they recognized and handled as two separate output by the gpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, typically you can use two external monitors when you don't need to use the built in display of your laptop.

If you want to use the internal monitor as well (means total of three), you may want to use a USB-HDMI adapter (basically a simple graphic adapter connected per USB) or some of the LG's models that can be connected directly using USB. In this case, it is advisable to check whether your OS supports the USB graphic adapter.

Comment: So if I want to use only the two external monitor, then I not need to use any adapter? I just plug them in (one in the vga one in the hdmi port) and everything will work?

Comment: Yes, if your 550LB model doesn't differ violently from what I've seen on the Asus website. You may have to enable the second monitor in your operating system, though. See this [Microsoft KB page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064) for details how to do it on Windows 7.

Comment: I confirm that simple work, and additionally I could use the internal screen too. So now I use my two external monitor and the biuilt-in one too.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question how many displays do you expect to use in total. If you want to use two external monitors plus your laptop built-in display, than I have to disappoint you, this is not possible. Not with a single graphic card. You would need to install additional graphic adapter to achieve this. There are some affordable USB-based options. (use google to find out more)

If you meant two external monitors without using laptop built-in display, then it is a bit easier, however there are still implications. You have to look up information on your particular laptop. In most cases VGA and HDMI outputs send the same signal and the only way of hooking up two monitors to one laptop is by means of docking station which will reroute your primary (built-in) display signal to one of your monitors.

Please consider using search before asking question. You might find this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop) interesting.

Comment: I want to use only the two external monitor, thanks for your reply, I will chek out that thread.

Comment: Does your laptop have a socket for docking station?

Comment: It's not clear to me what a docking station is. So how I can find out that? Here is the specificaton of my laptop: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550CC/

Comment: @NoNameProvided, then I suggest you Google docking station to read up on it