# How to run 2 external monitors on Dell n7520 laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, dell-inspiron

I'm having the n7520 Dell Inspiron notebook, and i'm trying to connect 2 external monitors to it, meaning i want 3 functional monitors at all.

i have bought VGA splitter and have 2 monitors connected to it, problem is that i see the same image over the two external monitors..

how can i make those 3 monitors to function separately ? heres are the specs: http://notebookspec.com/notebook/4731-DELL-Inspiron-N7520-V560404TH.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use two external monitor with a laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/739051/use-two-external-monitor-with-a-laptop)

Comment: More options here: http://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specs you posted your laptop has one VGA and one HDMI output.  If you want two external monitors, one would have to be VGA and one would have to be HDMI.

Comment: Ooh, good one. I looked over that :(

Comment: so basically if im connecting one though the VGA and one though the HDMI i be able to get them all 3 working separately ?

Comment: @somefolk Yes, one monitor to the VGA port and one to the HDMI port. The monitors themselves do not have to be VGA and HDMI exactly, as you could get adapters.

Comment: This newer question seems to suggest otherwise for this model: [Multiple monitors: VGA and HDMI not working properly together](http://superuser.com/questions/959200/multiple-monitors-vga-and-hdmi-not-working-properly-together)

Comment: @MC10 can you check out  Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 comment?  this is exactly the problem i'm currently having after getting the equipment to conned the third monitor through the hdmi port

Comment: @somefolk It looks like you cannot use the two ports at once, or at least not for different outputs. You will have to use a USB monitor adapter instead, I posted as an answer to the linked question in that comment: http://superuser.com/a/959232/403203