# How to extend Lenovo ThinkPad E460 with HDMI to two external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad, displayport

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad E460 and one HDMI out. How can I extend desktop to two external monitors? Extend desktop meaning different content. I'm not really sure how to do it.

Since there are lot of old answers available, maybe considering using displayport and linking multiple Dell monitors could be an option, and if I am able to get HDMI > DP running (without expensive docking stations).

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to the second external monitor to mirror the content of one the existing displays, or output different content to it?

Comment: Extend desktop meaning different content

Comment: @galacticninja i guess you didn't read it....

Comment: @John Four other users agreed with me that this question is a duplicate of [Connecting 2 External Monitors to a Laptop?](http://superuser.com/q/656/10259) If you don't think that this is a duplicate, please edit your question to clarify why.

Answer (score 2):

You could plug in a monitor to the existing HDMI and then add a USB to HDMI adaptor to add a 3rd monitor.

[Adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPEV1XK)

If you want to mirror the second display, you need to use a splitter.

[Splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CCMOMM0)