# Is it possible to connect 2 external monitors to a laptop if USB-C doesn't support video output?

Tags: windows, usb, laptop, video, multiple-monitors

It appears that my [laptop's](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c07071716) USB-C port doesn't support video output.  So, predictably, when I tried to connect a docking station, with 2 monitors attached, to the laptop's USB-C port, it didn't recognize new monitors.

In this situation, am I simply out of luck?  Or are there other solutions, like maybe external video cards?

There is a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/656/connecting-2-external-monitors-to-a-laptop) from over a decade ago about this very issue, so that gives me some hope.  However, most products mentioned there are either outdated or no longer exist.

If it matters at all, this laptop is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is still possible, the same way: using a USB graphics solution (DisplayLink).

Whether this is an option for you depends on what you want to do on those screens. Browsing? Text editing? Light graphics? Watching videos? That’ll work just fine. Serious graphics where color accuracy is required, 3D gaming? Not so much.

I developed software for a few years using a Dell D3100 (connected to USB 3.0) and two 1440p screens. That worked just fine.

You’ll have to find an up-to-date product of course. The keyword is “DisplayLink”. It may be hidden in the spec sheet. It is important to buy current-gen [DisplayLink](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics) products, using the latest HDMI/DisplayPort/USB standards available. Previous generations are still available but far less powerful. Always make sure to verify the graphics solution can actually deliver the resolution and refresh rate your displays need.